# SQL Tables with no direct relation

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL DB and I need to build a query to retrieve the information from a table that has no direct link with the main one.

[image: main layout]

The client is linked to the `client_identity_document` through its `UUID` and `client_identity_document` to the `identity_document` through the `uuid_identity_document`. I know I have to make an inner join, but I just started with `relational databases` and I don't know exactly the syntax to join tables that don't have direct relation.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and the expected result as formatted text, not as images (or links to them...) Also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select *
from client c 
inner join client_identity_document cid on c.UUID  = cid.UUID_Client 
inner join identity_document id on cid.uuid_identity_document = id.UUID
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Imagine that I have more columns in identy_document and I just want to retrieve two, for example. That syntax wouldn't work, right? I would have to be something like select name, surname  (select identity_number, valid_number from identity_document inner join identity_document id on ciud.uuid_indentity_document = id.uuid) from client c

Comment: @Stapler123 then you would just specify the columns you want instead of `*`. Once you've joined the tables, the columns from all joined table are available.